# Keyboard appear/disappear stuck a long time if TextInput carry a lot of text

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native to develop an app. Keyboard appear/disappear become very slow if `TextInput` carry a lot of text.

I googled and didn't find my answer. At last below errors came up, and app continued again. Anyone can help?

```
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```